# Why doesn't my picture appear next to my name when I add comments to a Google doc?

Tags: google-drive

When I add comments to a Google doc, there's a place-holder for my picture, but my actual picture does not show up. For other commenters, their picture does show up.

I have a picture set in my Google profile, and that picture appears in the top-right hand corner of my screen when I'm editing a doc. Why doesn't my picture show up in the comments box?

Comment: Still doesn't work for me either. It might be because of my privacy setting on my Google+ account though. I've wondered the same thing about Google Maps. It doesn't work there either. It works just fine in Google Groups, with the little pop-up profile selection when you join (for each group).

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-upload the picture from your [Google+](http://plus.google.com) account and check again.